# Retrieve Image from SqlServer into an ImageView

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

Im using xamarin with c#. I'm trying this code for preview an image from sql server into an imageview.

```
    ImageView imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.lk);
    Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnsd);
    btn.Click += delegate
    {

        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand("SELECT map fROM deliveryadress where deliveryid=2", con));
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            System.Byte[] data = new System.Byte[0];
            data = (System.Byte[])(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["map"]);
            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data);
            imageView = Image.FromStream(mem);


        };
```

But i'm getting error in 'Image.FromStream(mem)'.
If i will include Android.Media then i'm getting error in FromStream that image does not contain definition for FromStream.

Also i tried another aproach but i get FactoryReturned null:

```
    ImageView imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.lk);
    Button gg  = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnsd);

    gg.Click += delegate
    {
        string myBytes = "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";
        byte[] decByte3 = System.Convert.FromBase64String(myBytes);
        Bitmap myIcon = Bytes2Bimap(decByte3);
        Drawable myIconD = new BitmapDrawable(myIcon);
        imageView.Background = myIconD;

    };


}

public Bitmap Bytes2Bimap(byte[] b)
{
    if (b.Length != 0)
    {
        return BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(b, 0, b.Length);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Find out the length of the MemoryStream.  Make sure it contains correct number of bytes.

Comment: But the error i get is that image doent contain definition.how will i do that?

Comment: If the number of bytes is not correct than lot of different errors can occur.  Check length like this : Console.WriteLine(mem.Length.ToString());

Comment: ok i will try it. imageview should have type imageview.imagealpha or something like that?Also the error i get is before i will run my project and not in debug.Is it better to get my image as binary string and then to convert it in image?

Comment: Never use strings with binary data.  It should be a byte array.  Then convert to image.  Only time you should use string is if you packed the byte array into a 64 bit string (then unpacked).

Comment: Can you please give an easy example with my code?

Comment: Your code look good.  The only  issue I have is I do not know if the database ifs finding the map with deliveryid = 2 and the size of the map,  Getting the length of the MemoryStream will give a good idea if the data was stored and retrieved properly.  If you only had 4 bytes in the stream than I would know the image was bad.

Comment: But the error exists before running my project.

Comment: You must have more then one library with Image.  So use System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mem);

Comment: I'm getting :
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Image' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Drawing'

Comment: Please check another aproach i've tried

Comment: It looks like the issue is with the Android Libraries.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862868/how-to-add-system-drawing-in-xamarin

Comment: Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Image.FromStream(Stream)' WiOrderAndroid

Comment: It looks like in Android FromStream is not a static method.  So Image image = new Image(); imageView =  image.FromStream(mem);

Comment: Error CS0144 Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'Image'

Comment: I do not have an adroid version of VS to test code.  It looks like you need to include the full instance of the Image including namespace, similar to previous errors.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26758396/cannot-create-an-instance-of-an-abstract-class-from-documentation

Comment: Now i get error cant convert Image In ImageVIew    imageView=Image.FromStream(mem);

Comment: Now we are back at the beginning again.  What is the length of the MemoryStream?